# image not sharing using Social Sharing plugin on gmail

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, cordova-plugins

i want to share image which is get from my server and share that particular image on Gmail. please guide me

my image url like -

xyz.com/php/laravel/xyz/api/v1/folder/storagefolder/user/cover/h5SZsnbdwy3t68j0ghCfS5k2rCuGzXuYufy4KdPL.jpeg

Comment: This is resolve by convert  image url to base64.